# ¿Cómo puedo convertir la siguiente consulta en Laravel a Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subconsultas

```
SELECT [IDExplotacion]
      ,[Id]
      ,[IrNumContrato]
      ,[IrTipoRegistro]
      ,[IrFechaMovimiento]
      ,[ID_EstadoFactura]
      ,[IininRefCatastral]
      ,[IinTipoRef]
      ,[RefCatastral]
      FROM fianzas
     WHERE  [IrNumContrato] IN
    (SELECT [IrNumContrato]
      from fianzas
      group by [IrNumContrato]
      having count([IrNumContrato]) > 2

    )
```

He probado esto:

```
$fianzas = Fianza::whereIn('IrNumContrato', function ($query) {
        $query->select('IrNumContrato')
        ->from('fianzas')
        ->groupBy('IrNumContrato')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(IrNumContrato) > 2');
    })->get();
```

pero me da este error:

> "Method render does not exist."

Comment: $fianzas = Fianza::whereIn('IrNumContrato', function ($query) {
                       $query->select('IrNumContrato')
                      ->from('fianzas')
                      ->groupBy('IrNumContrato')
                      ->havingRaw('COUNT(IrNumContrato) > 2');
            })->get();
        He probado esto pero me da este erro  "Method render does not exist."

Comment: He probado el código con un modelo mío. Funciona correctamente (aparentemente). Por otro lado, en esta consulta no estás utilizando el método render; por lo que entiendo que la consulta funciona y el script sigue hasta un punto en el que llamas a este método y es ahí dónde da el error. Para verificarlo puedes poner en lugar de get(), toSql(), que devuelve la consulta sql; esta la pones en phpmyadmin y verás si funciona o no. SQL:` "select * from `fianzas` where `IrNumContrato ` in (select `IrNumContrato ` from `fianzas` group by `IrNumContrato ` having COUNT(IrNumContrato) > 2)"`